# export font from spreadsheet to python

Tags: python, csv, fonts, openoffice-calc

I have spreadsheet data in OpenOffice Calc that I would like to send to a python file.

The spreadsheet contains strings that use some odd fonts, and OpenOffice displays them properly. I can't find a way to get the font information into a .csv export; I would be just as happy to find a python method of extracting data from a spreadsheet file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to extract font information from a spreadsheet? Is it using Wingdings or something?

Comment: This question is confusing - are you wanting to preserve formatting or extract data?  I ask because you state that you would be just as happy to find a python method of extracting data from a spreadsheet file.

Comment: Are you trying to get the font name as one of the columns of your .csv? If not, what is your intent?

Comment: @WilliamKunkel -- essentially, yes. One string is in Hebrew, for example, and another uses an original font. (This whole thing is just for in-house use, there are no issues about the availability of the font.)

Comment: @PyNEwbie -- both. By "extract data" I was including formatting (i.e., font) data.

Comment: @MarkRansom -- getting the font name in the .csv would be a possible solution route, but I'd want it to be part of the export process rather than editing the spreadsheet to include a font column.

Comment: OK, I think I misunderstood the question (and others too apparently). Your goal is not to create a .csv file, that was just a technique you realized would not work; your goal is to read the spreadsheet (both data and formatting, including the font) into a Python program.

Answer (score 0):

CSV files don't store font meta data. Instead, you should try to convert the stored spreadsheet into an XLS format (Or another format of your choice).

Then, you can use python libraries that support the format such as:

http://www.python-excel.org/